# Get Auto foreign key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to make generalized master search for my *MS-SQL* data. Let me explain what I had done till now:

- Firstly, I fill one combo box with all the table names.
- Then, fill second combo box with columns of selected table from first combo box.

I run general database query like `select * from combobox1.text where combobox2.text='someValue'`. Everything works fine for me, but I am not able to get foreign key data which is primary in another table.

**What i need**

suppose **Table A** has columns: 1 primary key, 2 name of id. And **Table 2** with: 1 as primary key column, 2 as address column, and 3 as foreign key column. When I run `select * from table2`

I get result of foreign key in terms of id, I want value of table1.2 column value.

**Why i am asking**

This because with this type of system, I can query each and every row in database without manual coding for each table.

Images to explain better

Employee Master Table
[image: Employee Master Table]

Attendance Table

[image: Attendance Table]

Result i want [image: Result table]

Comment: Could you please [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) your table schema with test data? So that can suggest you the solutions for same.

Comment: It seems you want a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 "Join (SQL)"), which is one of the fundamental operations one can do in SQL. And SQL Server [supports joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx "Join Fundamentals") too – how fortuitous, don't you find. :)

Comment: I know that i can attain result by join but in that case i need to write join queries manually but i want that i automatically get foreign key attached table Name as explained above.